# How to use the json data in console for handlebars template design (node.js)

Tags: html, json, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using an api to get JSON data in my node.js app and it works when I print it in console, but I can't get the data to display on my app template.

Here is my code for the api I'm getting the data from:

```
Router.get('/movie/search', function(req,res){
  var search=req.query;

  imdb.getReq({name: search.moviename},(err,things) => {
    console.log(things);
    if (err) {

    }
      JSON:true;
        res.render('movie/search', {movieList: things});

  });
});
```

Here is the console data:

```
TVShow {
  title: 'Gu Family Book',
  _year_data: '2013–',
  year: 2013,
  rated: 'N/A',
  released: 2013-04-07T21:00:00.000Z,
  runtime: 'N/A',
  genres: 'Action, Comedy, Fantasy',
  director: 'N/A',
  writer: 'N/A',
  actors: 'Sung-ha Jo, Hye-Young Jung, Hee-won Kim, Sung-jae Lee',
  plot: 'N/A',
  languages: 'Korean',
  country: 'South Korea',
  awards: 'N/A',
  poster: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcwM2IxNWYtYWY2Yy00NTFjLTljYjgtYWQ1YmJkMzAzODNjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzE4MDkyNTA@._V1_SX300.jpg',
  metascore: 'N/A',
  rating: '8.1',
  votes: '591',
  imdbid: 'tt2816734',
  type: 'series',
  totalseasons: 1,
  response: 'True',
  series: true,
  imdburl: 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2816734',
  _episodes: [],
  start_year: 2013,
  end_year: null }
```

Handlebars template code:

```
{{#each movieList}}
  <div class="movie">
    <img src="{{poster}}">
    <br>Type:{{type}}</br>
    <br class="movieinfo">Year:{{_year_data}}</br>
    <br>IMDb:{{imdbid}}<br>
    <br>Discription:{{plot}}</br>
{{/each}}
```

The data won't display on my app.

Comment: `things` is an array or object?

Comment: Did you try `movieList: JSON.parse(things)`

Comment: i just tried it didn't work it printed this error. 'Unhandled rejection SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0'.

Comment: Do you get any output?

Comment: yes i did, I got the an output.

Answer (score 0):

`things` is *not* an array, but an object. By `#eaching` over `movieList` you are not iterating over a list of `Movie` objects, but rather over each property in your single object; ie, `title`, `_year_data`, `year`, etc. Inside of your `#each` block, each item within mustaches is being used as a property key in a lookup on the currently iterated property; ex., `title.poster`, `title.type`, etc.

Since we are not dealing with a list of `Movie` objects, but a single one, let's rename our template data object to `movie`. Next, in our template, we can remove the `#each` block, and simply directly access the properties of our `movie` object.

Render call:

```
res.render('movie/search', { movie: things });
```

Template:

```
<div class="movie">
    <img src="{{movie.poster}}">
    <p>Type:{{movie.type}}</p>
    <p class="movieinfo">Year:{{movie._year_data}}</p>
    <p>IMDb:{{movie.imdbid}}</p>
    <p>Description:{{movie.plot}}</p>
</div>
```

Additionally, I don't know what the `JSON:true;` line is intended to do in your code, but it should be removed. Also, in your template you are missing a closing div tag and erroneously including closing break tags. Correct usage of the HTML break tag can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br). I have corrected these errors in the template and fixed the typo in "Description".